# Router Event not triggering in Child Component but does in Parent Component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a child component that wants to have access to the current router url, which I can use for redirection upon login.

My constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((e:any) => 
    {
        if(e.url)
        {
            this.url = e.url;
        }
    });
}
```

However when I do a route change when a user clicks on a part of the component that needs to be logged in to access like below, the url is undefined

```
this.router.navigate(['login'], {
    queryParams: {
        return: this.url
    }
});
```

The weird thing is that this exact same code is working for the same scenario for the Parent component.

Is there a reason why the child component is not getting the router event so as to set the url?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

**Details of your problem**:

The code in your constructor is updating the component's url variable each time there is an update in the route. If you put a breakpoint at line `this.url = e.url;`, you will see that it fires a lot of times, and it gets a different event item each time, e.g. [`NavigationStart`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart), [`NavigationEnd`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd) etc (as the `e:any` item you've defined), see [router event](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) for more details.

**Solution**:

Assign your `url` variable with the `router.url` variable like so:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.url = router.url;
}
```